# Instantiate C++ templated class with arg, *and* as array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, instantiation, argument-passing

I have a C++ templated class whose constructor has a default argument.

Can it be instantiated with a nondefault arg, *and* as an array?  (If not, why not?)

Either one works, but not both at once (in g++ 4.6.3):

```
template <class T> class Cfoo {
  public:
    int x;
    Cfoo(int xarg=42) : x(xarg) {}
};

Cfoo<int> thisWorks[10];
Cfoo<int> thisWorks(43);
Cfoo<int> thisFails(43)[10];
Cfoo<int> thisFails[10](43);
Cfoo<int>[10] thisFails(43);
// (even crazier permutations omitted)
```

Comment: `Cfoo<int> arr[3] = {42, 42, 42};`

Comment: After three hours, still no ka-sploosh award for standards diving?  jrok's solution worked in the (less trivial) code that I needed this for.

Comment: Both jrok and Mark B provide helpful workarounds.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are correct: You can only default-construct elements in an array while you can pass any argument you like to a single object construction.

If you need a collection, in C++98 you can utilize `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Cfoo<int> >(10, 43);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant create an array using non-default constructor.